# How to name the parameter that holds `next` middleware in the chain?

Tags: naming, python-3.x

I am writing an implementation of middleware chain in Python. Here is how a middleware function looks like:

```
async def logger(ctx, next):
    print(f"Started doing stuff with {ctx}")
    await next()
    print(f"Finished doing stuff with {ctx}")
```

And this is how you use it:

```
app.use(logger)
app.use(some_other_middleware)
app.use(process_request)
...
```

`next` argument is the indirect reference to the next middleware in the chain. In Javascript, where I take the inspiration for this design from, it's very common to name this argument `next`. However, in Python `next` is already a builtin function, and it's better not to shadow it. Also, code linters complain about hiding a builtin.

So, I have to come up with an alternative name that would be the same level clear, short and readable. Unfortunately, English is not my first language, so I don't really see any alternatives, and made-up things like `_next`, `next_` or `anext` look extremely ugly to me.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `child`, `nextMiddleware`, `chain`, `doNext`, `continueChain`, `successor`?

Comment: @Samuel, `proceed`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this specific case I have evaded the need to name the argument by switching to asynchronous generators:

```
async def logger(ctx):
    print(f"Started doing stuff with {ctx}")
    yield
    print(f"Finished doing stuff with {ctx}")
```

To me this seems to be better than `next`, because it's using the semantics of language.

If I didn't switch, I would have used `proceed`:

```
async def logger(ctx, proceed):
    print(f"Started doing stuff with {ctx}")
    await proceed()
    print(f"Finished doing stuff with {ctx}")
```

Answer (score 0):

When naming WSGI Middleware, I usually use the word "app".

The app is the application that the current middleware will be wrapping. The application could actually be an application that had been wrapped by another middleware, but the current middleware doesn't need to care about that, as a middleware wrapped application is still an application.

Why is this a better name than `next`? Because it's a noun.